# Twisted Conch SSHCommandClientEndpoint issues with ssh keys

Tags: ssh, twisted, ssh-keys

I'm trying to open a basic ssh connection using conch and I'm using SSHCommandClientEndpoint to do so. And the connection works if I pass it a password, but I want to do it using ssh keys. However, anytime i pass in the keys argument it fails to authenticate. I can ssh into my machine using the keys on my own so I do not know what the issue is.

Here is my code:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, defer, reactor, task
from twisted.conch.endpoints import SSHCommandClientEndpoint
from twisted.conch.ssh import keys

async def conchSSH():
    
    finished = defer.Deferred()

    class ShowOutput(protocol.Protocol):
        received = b""
        def dataReceived(self, data):
            self.received += data
        def connectionLost(self, reason):
            finished.callback(self.received)

    key = keys.Key.fromFile("id_rsa")
    endpoint = SSHCommandClientEndpoint.newConnection(reactor, "ls", "user", (i have my host here), 22, keys=[key])
    factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(ShowOutput)
    await endpoint.connect(factory)
    print("SSH response:", await finished)

task.react(lambda *a, **k: defer.ensureDeferred(conchSSH()))
```

but then i get this error

```
main function encountered error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/latentbuildbot/master_branch/sandbox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 735, in errback
    self._startRunCallbacks(fail)
  File "/home/user/latentbuildbot/master_branch/sandbox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 798, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/home/user/latentbuildbot/master_branch/sandbox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 892, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/home/user/latentbuildbot/master_branch/sandbox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1792, in gotResult
    _inlineCallbacks(r, gen, status, context)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/user/latentbuildbot/master_branch/sandbox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1693, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = context.run(
  File "/home/user/latentbuildbot/master_branch/sandbox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 518, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/home/user/latentbuildbot/master_branch/my_master/config/twistedconch.py", line 21, in conchSSH
    await endpoint.connect(factory)
twisted.conch.endpoints.AuthenticationFailed: Connection lost while authenticating
```

Comment: Is `id_rsa` in the current directory when you run this?  Your code works perfectly for me, when I include the whole path to the key.

Comment: it is in the current directory, that is so strange. I included more of my error message

Comment: Can you do `ssh -i ./id_rsa user@host ls` from a command line?

Comment: Yes that does work from the command line

Comment: Just to double-check, do you understand that "current directory" does not mean "the directory where the script lives"?  If you `cd ~` and `python latentbuildbot/master_branch/my_master/config/twistedconch.py`, it's not going to find the file.  You can compute the proper directory using `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.

Comment: Yes i do know that, I have managed to get it to print the corresponding public key by doing
`print(key.public().toString("OPENSSH"))`So i know it is finding the file

Comment: I have noticed that when I do 
`print(key.toString("OPENSSH"))`
it gives a different private key that what is in the actual file, but it makes the same public key.
The private key in my files starts off as
`-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`
but then the one it prints off starts as
`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
I don't know if that can be causing the issues

Comment: As long as it maps to the same public key, that's just two different formats for the same information.  I admit, I'm confused.

Comment: Same lol. I appreciated you taking the time to help :)

Comment: Have you tried passing an absolute path name to `Key.fromFile`? `id_rsa` is a pretty common file name for an SSH key, and it seems possible to me that you've got multiple keys on your filesystem containing different keys.